# Specify an icon for app with Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, icons

I am have some trouble specifying a custom icon in my WPF applicaion. I went to Properties/Application and down in resource I pointed towards where the icon is stored (Resources/MyIcon.ico). However when I run the app I get the default icon.

Has anyone else seen similar problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icon shown in the taskbar and on a form is the icon associated with the *form*, not the application.  (After all, two forms can have two different icons)

You need to change the Icon property of your main Window in XAML.

Comment: -1 because that's not quite correct; each window's icon can be specified, but if it's not specified it is taken from the Application icon. However, in debug mode the app icon is not visible because of the VS hosting process (see the MSDN page, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.icon(v=VS.100).aspx). I'm sure I got it working in debug mode as well (without turning off the hosting process) but don't remember how. Anyway, if you set the app icon, all the windows in the application will have it by default when running outside VS.